# Is there any restriction on whom can use the Seoul–Pyongyang hotline and for what type of communication it can be used?

Tags: north-korea, south-korea

> North Korea’s state media outlet, KCNA, also said all inter-Korean
> communication channels resumed operation at 10 a.m. Tuesday (0100 GMT)
> in line with an agreement between Moon and Kim.
>
> “The two leaders have explored ways to recover relations by exchanging
> letters on several occasions, and agreed to restore severed hotlines
> as a first step for that process,” Park said in a statement. “They
> have also agreed to regain trust as soon as possible and foster
> progress on relations again.”
>
> **KCNA touted the reopening of the hotlines as “a big stride in
> recovering the mutual trust and promoting reconciliation.”**
>
> North Korea cut the hotlines in June 2020 as cross-border ties soured
> after a failed second summit in February 2019 between Kim and former
> U.S. President Donald Trump, which Moon had offered to mediate.

https://www.theglobeandmail.com/world/article-north-and-south-korea-restore-once-severed-hotline-blue-house/

I was reading about the hotline and was wondering how the hotline is used. However, the Wikipedia article about it provides very little information about how the hotline is used by both sides. Is there any restriction on whom can use the hotline and for what type of communication it can be used? And is the rule binding for both sides or does both sides have their own rules?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seoul%E2%80%93Pyongyang_hotline

Comment: Whoever is at the other side of the line represents that country government, so I would expect that each government decides who represents them for this function. For the "what are they used for", the Wikipedia page you linked gives a nice list, including how many physical lines are used for each type of communication.